# Orientation Working on simulator but not on device for ios7

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, orientation

I have seen multiple copies of the same question.but it has not supported my cause.

i have tried subclassing the navigationController adding category for the navigation controller and when i tried all these the methods shouldAutoRotate and supportedInterfaceOrientations gets invoked for Both the navigationcontroller and view controller but the device stays in portrait view only.

```
#import "UINavigationController+Rotation.h"

@implementation UINavigationController (Rotation)
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

BOOL result = self.topViewController.shouldAutorotate;

return result;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

NSUInteger result = self.topViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations;

return result;
}

@end
```

Is some thing that i do wrong?

Comment: Please check if you haven't disabled orientation change in iOS settings on your device

Comment: it is enabled and i can see it in my info.plist

Comment: I mean iOS Control Center option like here https://www.dropbox.com/s/od2n9n6tojgbga9/exm.jpg

Comment: thanks i never thought of that

Comment: Important to say, iOS defines a new state in rotation : when the screen is flat! I mean when the device is laid in a desk and flat, which is a different state. I got crazy with that sometime ago, and it´s defined in the different states of screen orientation as well.

Comment: Please look at my answer may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Call this method form `viewdidload`:

```
-(void)rotateCameraView {
          [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
          [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector:   @selector(deviceOrientationDidChange:) name:   
   UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object: nil];
          }
```

When you rotate device this method will call automatically

```
-(void)deviceOrientationDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {   
    //Obtaining the current device orientation 
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];     
    //Ignoring    specific orientations 
    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp
    ||    orientation == UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown || orientation ==  
    UIDeviceOrientationUnknown) { return; } 
    if ((UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)   
    ||UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)) ||   
    (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation) ||   
    UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation))) { 
    //still saving the  current orientation 
    currentOrientation = orientation; } [self   
    performSelector:@selector(orientationChangedMethod) withObject:nil  
    afterDelay:0]; 
}

-(void)orientationChangedMethod
{
   switch (currentOrientation) {

       case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:

           if (isOrientationEffect==YES)
           {
               appDelegate.imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);

                //                if (!isPurchased) 
                //                { 
                // 
                //                    [self buttonFrameWithIad]; 
                //             } 
                //                else 
                //                { 
                //                  [self buttonFrameWithoutIad]; 
                //                }

               [self MakeTransformRotation];
           }
           [UIView beginAnimations:@"rotateView" context:nil];
           [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
           [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.35f];

           camDefaultImg.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
           [UIView commitAnimations];

           break;
       case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:

           if (isOrientationEffect==YES)
           {
           } 
      }
```